# Using rsync to backup Windows Server 2008 R2 files to Ubuntu, using plink for SSH

Tags: windows-server-2008, ubuntu, ssh, rsync, putty

I am trying to configure rsync for backing up files on a Windows Server 2008 R2 box to a Ubuntu box. All (non-test) data must be encrypted.

I have managed to get it working using just rsync, recieving date from port 873, but I am having trouble using plink as well.

Here is my configuration:

**Ubuntu**

rsyncd.conf:

```
log file = /var/log/rsync.log
[ukwindb1backup]
   path = /home/ukwindb1/rsync
   comment = Backup
   uid = ukwindb1
   gid = ukwindb1
   use chrott = true
   read only = false
   auth users = ukwindb1
   secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.secrets
```

Rsync deamon has been started, and there is a "ukwindb1" account, with a SSH public key for authentication. All SSH traffic is on a different port, not 22.

The password for "ukwindb1", stored in the rsyncd.secrets file is not the same as for the Ubuntu account (though passwords are disabled for SSH login).

**Windows Server**

I have cygwin installed, and have managed to get rsync to work, using this batch file:

```
rsync.exe -qrtz --password-file=/home/Administrator/secret --delete "/cygdrive/c/Backups" ukwindb1@[removed-ip]::ukwindb1backup
pause
```

I also have the Putty programs installed, and want to use plink to connect to the other server, so that I can use Pageant to manage my passworded keys.

I tried this batch file, to connect to the SSH server using plink, and it worked fine:

```
plink -ssh -P [removed-port] -l ukwindb1 -i C:\ukwindb1.ppk [removed-ip]
pause
```

Now, when I tried this batch file for putting the two together, it failed:

```
rsync.exe -qrtz -e "plink -ssh -P [removed-port] -l ukwindb1 -i C:\ukwindb1.ppk [removed-ip]" --delete "/cygdrive/c/Backups" ukwindb1@[removed-ip]::ukwindb1backup
pause
```

Any ideas? What exactly am I doing wrong?

In addition:

Do I actually need the rsync daemon running?

Can I specify a directory on the server, from the client end, rather than "::ukwindb1backup"?

Comment: When the rsync batch file fails, what error does it produce?

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/277859/257058 ,  that can be useful. It helped me to use rsync.exe with plink with cygnative wrapper. `rsync -vrn -e 'cygnative plink -batch -load bbb' :/root .`

Answer (score 2):

I think you can skip `rsyncd` and `plink` entirely, by rearranging your architecture a bit (which will have other benefits).

I believe that `rsyncd` daemon doesn't actually need to be running to do a basic rsync for backup purposes.  `rsync` normally just connects to the other box over SSH, fires up an instance of rsync on the far side, and the two `rsync`s talk to each other over ssh -- the `rsyncd` daemon isn't really involved.  `rsyncd` is normally used to serve content for download by multiple clients (like a mirror server).

In this setup, I assume that the box receiving the backup (the Ubuntu box) is the more "trusted" system (from a security perspective) --- not because it's Ubuntu, but because backup servers naturally have to hold data for multiple sensitive hosts.  As such, I would recommend initiating the `rsync` from the Ubuntu box, and setting the key trust relationship so that it's the Windows box that trusts the Ubuntu box, and not the other way around.  This would mean [setting up sshd under Cygwin](http://www.noah.org/ssh/cygwin-sshd.html), and locking it down (with a host-based firewall) so that only connections from your backup server are permitted.

You could then simply execute:

```
rsync -qrtz windowsbox:/path/to/files /path/to/ubuntu/backups
```

... which also demonstrates how to specify the directory on the serving side.

As the next troubleshooting step, I would drop trying to use `rsyncd`, temporarily leaving out key-based authentication just as you did in your earlier troubleshooting, and just try a simple rsync (of a couple of test files) using password-based authentication.

Once you get the basic sync working, you'll also want to look at `rsync`'s `--modify-window` option, which will ignore the small drift in timestamps that can result from the differences in how Windows and Unix-likes handle seconds in timestamps.  Otherwise, files that could otherwise be skipped will get copied over and over again.

I also strongly recommend leaving off the `--delete` option until after you have finished debugging and testing your solution.  One typo and you can delete far more than you intended.